# Best way to convert NSString output of x86 registers to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to display the output of the gdb command "info registers" in my cocoa app (in a UITableView). In order to do that, I will need to convert the output which is currently a string into an array. Currently, the string output looks like this :

```
"rax            0x10004005  268451845
    rbx            0x0  0
    rcx            0x7fff5fbfe948   140734799800648
    rdx            0x0  0
    rsi            0x7000006    117440518
    rdi            0x7fff5fbfea80   140734799800960
    rbp            0x7fff5fbfe9a0   0x7fff5fbfe9a0
    rsp            0x7fff5fbfe948   0x7fff5fbfe948
    r8             0x1e03   7683
    r9             0x0  0
    r10            0x800    2048
    r11            0x206    518
    r12            0x1e03   7683
    r13            0x800    2048
    r14            0x7fff5fbfea80   140734799800960
    r15            0x7000006    117440518
    rip            0x7fff823d8d7a   0x7fff823d8d7a <mach_msg_trap+10>
    eflags         0x206    518
    cs             0x2f 47
    ss             0x0  0
    ds             0x0  0
    es             0x0  0
    fs             0x10 16
    gs             0x48 72"
```

How do i convert this string into an array such that it looks like this?

```
   "rax            0x10004005   268451845,
    rbx            0x0  0,
    rcx            0x7fff5fbfe948   140734799800648,
    rdx            0x0  0,
    rsi            0x7000006    117440518,
    rdi            0x7fff5fbfea80   140734799800960,
    rbp            0x7fff5fbfe9a0   0x7fff5fbfe9a0,
    rsp            0x7fff5fbfe948   0x7fff5fbfe948,
    r8             0x1e03   7683,
    r9             0x0  0,
    r10            0x800    2048,
    r11            0x206    518,
    r12            0x1e03   7683,
    r13            0x800    2048,
    r14            0x7fff5fbfea80   140734799800960,
    r15            0x7000006    117440518,
    rip            0x7fff823d8d7a   0x7fff823d8d7a <mach_msg_trap+10>,
    eflags         0x206    518,
    cs             0x2f 47,
    ss             0x0  0,
    ds             0x0  0,
    es             0x0  0,
    fs             0x10 16,
    gs             0x48 72"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *myArray = [mysHexString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: This works fine in deleting the "\n"'s from the array, but what about the "\t"'s?